# semantic-ui sidebar below topbar

Tags: sidebar, semantic-ui

I have a ".ui.inverted.menu" top bar.
Now I want to add a "ui.sidebar.inverted.vertical.menu" below the topbar.

But I can't figure out how to do it, the sidebar will always push away the topbar, and not appear below the topbar.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

ps. Sorry for bad grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your sidebar with a custom context.

Instead of doing something like this:
$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar();

You need to point the sidebar at the element that you want to attach it to otherwise it will attach to your main `<body>` tag and push away all content underneath it. In this case, the context should be a `<div>` element in the same hierarchy as your `.ui.inverted.menu`.

If your HTML looks something like:

```
<div class="ui inverted menu">
    <a class="item">Open Sidebar</a>
</div>
<div class="otherstuff">
    <div class="ui sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your initialization code should look something like this:

```
$('.ui.sidebar')
  .sidebar({
    context: $('.otherstuff')
  })
```

Here's a very quick demo (you may need to tweak some CSS styles depending on your own content) http://jsfiddle.net/8po0b10v/